# Prevent insertion if the records already exist in iphone sqlite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, sqlite

I want to insert a record into an sqlite table in iphone if it's not already present.

I am using three fields named as

- `id(integer primary key Auto increment)`
- `name(text)`
- `address(text)`

If a name exists in the table then it should not insert any row.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make field `name` a `UNIQUEKEY` and rest will be handeled by the sqlite itself.

Here is Create table query:

> CREATE TABLE YourTableName (id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT DEFAULT 0,name text UNIQUE, address text)

Comment: you mean even after making name `UNIQUEKEY` you are able to insert redundent record?

Comment: @rptawasthi 1 more thing if record is not inserted then it should alert (Name already exist) I am using sqlite3_exec method....please suggest...

Comment: If usin sqlite3_exec print NSSAsert in else, that will help you? As message will be like violating UNIQUE key contraint. Get help from that.

Comment: Sure! gave a nice night.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this ([source](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)):

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO TableName (Field) VALUES 'value'
```

Comment: I have tried this but didn't succeed as above query doesn't work when id is taken  as primary key and autoincrement both.